# Angular: HighChart TreeMap is not updating with the new data

Tags: angular, highcharts, treemap, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to update my highcharts treemap with new data but it dosen't seem to reflect when I click on update. Only the title getting changed.

Also the option which was suggested on multiple page's dont seems to work:

```
this.chartOptions.series[0].data = this.datatable; // ERROR
```

Here is the whole code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-bv64br) and update method:

```
handleUpdate() {
this.chartOptions.title = {
  text: 'updated'
};
this.datatable = [{
  name: 'A',
  value: 6,
  colorValue: 1
}, {
  name: 'B',
  value: 6,
  colorValue: 2
}];
this.chartOptions.data = this.datatable;
this.updateFlag = true;
}
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

New data must be entered into series in the chartOption object.
Based on your code, I modified the handleUpdate code.

```
handleUpdate() {
  this.chartOptions.title = {
    text: 'updated',
  };
  this.datatable = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      value: 4,
      colorValue: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      value: 6,
      colorValue: 2,
    },
  ];

  // modified code 1
  this.chartOptions.series[0] = {
    type: 'treemap',
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    alternateStartingDirection: true,
    data: this.datatable,
  };
  
  // modified code 2
  this.chartOptions.series[0]['data'] = this.datatable;

  this.updateFlag = true;
}
```

Use modified code 1 or 2.

If you write the code as below, you will face the following error.

```
this.chartOptions.series[0].data = this.datatable;
```

Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesOptionsType'.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions'.

This is because 'data' object is defined as optional.

```
export interface SeriesTreemapOptions extends PlotTreemapOptions, SeriesOptions {
    data?: Array<(number|null|PointOptionsObject)>;
    dataParser?: undefined;
    dataURL?: undefined;
    stack?: undefined;
    type: "treemap";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missed chart reference, there is no callback that sets a reference to the chart. If you want updated chart refer to the chartRef and it will be working.

```
  chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = chart => {
    this.chartRef = chart;
  };
```

Live demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-nteedw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Highcharts wrapper for Angular:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#installing